# Nusoap y symfony3

Tags: symfony3

Problema para conectar con web service. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$client = new \nusoap_client('clientesoap', true);
$param= array('parametro1'=> value1, 'parámetro2'=>'value2');
$result = $client->call('metodo', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
```

los dos parámetros que le paso con los solicitados por el método del webservice pero no ingresa.

Comment: Algún error al ejecutar la llamadas contra el webservice o algo reseñable que dé una pista de por donde tirar?

Comment: Voy a descargarme el nusoap para reproducir tu problema, mientras échale un vistazo a mi respuesta usando el cliente SOAP nativo de PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la definición de los parámetros de la llamada a `Synchro` (en el [`WSDL`](http://v3lademo.fidely.net/fnet3web/proxy/wsdl_ca.php?v=01.02)) aparece:

```
<element name="SynchroRequest">
  <complexType>
    <sequence>
      <element name="kind" type="int"/>
      <element name="campaignId" type="long"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
</element>
```

Como ves no existe ningún parámetro llamado `parameters`, pero sí un `<sequence>` (una matriz), por lo que debemos enviarle una matriz en la que, por ejemplo, el primer elemento tenga los parámetros `kind` y `campaignId` deseados.

Es probable que esté diseñado así para permitir sincronizar varias campañas en una única llamada agregando tantos elementos a la matriz como necesitemos.

Usando el cliente nativo SOAP de PHP:

```
<?php
$client = new \SoapClient('http://v3lademo.fidely.net/fnet3web/proxy/wsdl_ca.php?v=01.02');
$result = $client->__soapCall(
    'Synchro',
    [
        [
            'kind'=> 3,
            'campaignId'=>'803'
        ]
    ]
);
// $result->answerCode / $result->session
var_export($result);
```

Usando `nusoap`:

```
<?php
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new \nusoap_client('http://v3lademo.fidely.net/fnet3web/proxy/wsdl_ca.php?v=01.02', true);
$param = array('kind' => 3, 'campaignId' => '803');
$result = $client->call('Synchro', [ $param ], '', '', false, true);
// $result['answerCode'] / $result['session']
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Es un sequence, una matriz, por lo que le paso una matriz y funciona correcto. Voy a documentarlo.

Comment: Con `nusoap` tienes `$result['answerCode']` y `$result['session']` y con el cliente nativo `$result->answerCode` y `$result->session`. Voy a editar la respuesta.